# Aura Application Events vs Component Events ( clarification )

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am reading about aura events and I am a little confused.

In the documentation it says that Component and Application events have the below phases:

- Application Event  - [bubble, capture, default ]
- Component Event  - [bubble, capture ]

(Please correct me if I am wrong )What I have understood so far is that bubble and capture phases are propagated following the same logic in both events, so my question is: if application events can do the same ( and more ) as component Events, why do we need Component events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component events are "local," and thus more efficient. It's also easier to predict which components will handle them, since they only travel between the document root and the target. These events are used to communicate from child to parent components, which are, by far, the most common use of events. Most events should be component events.

Application events are "global," so they can be handled by every registered component in the DOM. This is less efficient, but allows for communication between any two components in the hierarchy, parents, children, siblings, and even completely unrelated components. The reason why application events have bubble and capture phases at all are so that a parent component can restrict the application event's scope to just its children components.

Application events that propagate through the entire DOM will often be wasteful and may have unintended side effects, while to prevent this problem requires extra event handlers to contain the scope of the event. In addition, if the event is intended to be handled by child components, you can't target one specific child; all children will receive the event even if it's not applicable to them.

So, in summary, application events are intended to be used in situations where you cannot directly communicate between two components, or where it would be unnecessarily complicated to do so, but they should not be used any more than necessary because they are hard to control and inefficient compared to component events.

Comment: makes sense "The reason why application events have bubble and capture phases at all are so that a parent component can restrict the application event's scope to just its children components.", thanks you for your help